# Working with EVP and OpenSSL, coding in C

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, digital-signature, evp-cipher

I've seen many questions on OpenSSL and EVP, but not very many clear answers, but I figured I'd still post my question here and hope for better feedback.

The materials given to me are a signed file "symmetrickey.bin", an RSA key set "privatekey_A.pem", "publickey_A.pem", and the other user's public key "publickey_B.pem".

What I need to do is:

1. Unsign `symmetrickey.bin` and store it into a text file.
2. Encrypt a `message.txt` using the `symmetrickey.txt` and some algorithm like AES for example.
3. Sign the encrypted message with `privatekey_A.pem` and write to a file `cipher.bin`.
4. After that I need to unsign and verify the signature on `cipher.bin`.
5. Then decrypt the message with our symmetric key then write to another file.

The issues I'm having are understanding how to implement the OpenSSL EVP libraries. The API page is not very clear about where the values for each function comes from. For example, `EVP_OpenInit()` where am I getting `ek` or the length of `ek` "ekl"? Is "prvi" a private key? And how am I to know the type? These are things I'm not given.

I've looked at many implementations and most don't answer my questions or they give crazy code with little to no explanation of what's going on or where values are coming from. I'm posting here as a last resort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sign/unsign key part I need further information, how is this signature done? For example, is this signature an X byte length at the end of the file and can then easily be removed?

For items 2-5 in your list the following code will surely assist, it is based on the examples from openssl documentation with more comments and adaptations for your needs. Feel free to ask if you have any questions that are not commented!

#### crpytor.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#define APPNAME "C"

#define CHUNK_SIZE 512
int do_crypt(FILE *in, FILE *out, int do_encrypt)
{
    /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
    unsigned char inbuf[CHUNK_SIZE];
    unsigned char outbuf[CHUNK_SIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int inlen;
    int outlen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    /* Bogus key and IV: we'd normally set these from
     * another source.
     */
    unsigned char key[] = { 0x13, 0xa3, 0xb4, 0xc1, 0x24, 0x19, 0xf5, 0x23, 0x18, 0xef, 0xca, 0x12, 0x4c, 0x9f, 0x14, 0xfe };
    unsigned char iv[] = { 0x92, 0x1c, 0x23, 0x3f, 0x5e, 0x10, 0x3d, 0x9a };
    /* Don't set key or IV because we will modify the parameters */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    /* Using Blowfish encryption with cbc algorithm, you can use whichever is supported in openssl if you wish */
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_bf_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length(&ctx, 16);
    /* We finished modifying parameters so now we can set key and IV */
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);
    for(;;)
    {
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, CHUNK_SIZE, in);
        if(inlen <= 0) break;
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen))
        {
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return -1;
        }
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    }
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen))
    {
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return -1;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    rewind(in);
    rewind(out);
    return 0;
}

/* This is the standalone encryptor entry point */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *encode_file;
    FILE *decode_file;
    int enc_or_dec;
    if (argc < 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [plain file] [encrypted file] [0/1 deccrypt/encrypt]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    encode_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    decode_file = fopen(argv[2], "w+");
    /* Stupid decimal translation */
    enc_or_dec = *argv[3]-48;

    do_crypt(encode_file, decode_file, enc_or_dec);
    return 0;
}
```

And the Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc cryptor.c -o cryptor -g -lcrypto -I ../openssl-1.0.1f-host/include
clean:
    rm cryptor
```

This code does not use `EVP_OpenInit()` because it is used only for decryption, while my method (and your needs) require both encryption or decryption. While you can use `EVP_OpenInit()` to initialize a decryption context, I replaced the single call suitable only for decryption with two calls suitable for both encryption and decryption.

From the man page:

> `EVP_OpenInit()` initializes a cipher context `ctx` for decryption with
>   cipher type. It decrypts the encrypted symmetric key of length `ekl`
>   bytes passed in the `ek` parameter using the private key `priv`.  The IV
>   is supplied in the `iv` parameter. `EVP_OpenUpdate()` and `EVP_OpenFinal()`
>   have exactly the same properties as the `EVP_DecryptUpdate()` and
>   `EVP_DecryptFinal()` routines, as documented on the `EVP_EncryptInit(3)`
>   manual page.

`EVP_OpenInit()` for key files

If the signed file you are referring to is a public key file in RSA/DSA or similar format, you can use [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400364/getting-error-in-evp-openinit-of-openssl-evp-api-for-rsa-decryption-in-c) for a better method than mine as it does the key extraction from the file automatically (and uses `EVP_OpenInit()` like you require)

Comment: For part 1, i'm not exactly told how the file was signed. The key pair i was given to use as my own ("privatekey_A.pem" and "publickey_A.pem") where generated as RSA keys. The "symmetrickey.bin" contains a symmetric session key. The file was then signed by the senders private key. I'm guess they also have an RSA key set and possibly used the EVP libraries to seal it. My job on that step is to use EVP_open() to unsign and store the session key in a .txt file. My understanding is that after unsigning, this file will be used as our key for encryption.

Comment: Hi Chris, did you check out the StackOverflow link I provided? It includes a fairly complete example with full explanations for your case

Comment: I believe it does, there was a link from that page that I followed and it gave an example for EVP_Seal(), and EVP_Open(). I'll start compiling code the next few days to confirm it all works together but this has given me much more clarification for now. I'll post an edit once I get it all working for the next person confused by the "man evp" page. :)

Comment: I remember struggling with the openssl documentation myself more than once... It really does require some work